# Cross platform compatibility in C++

Tags: c++, bluetooth, serial-port

I have an Arduino micro-controller that sends data to a HC-05 Bluetooth module via a serial port. Since the implementation of connecting to a communication port is specific to the OS, the include files will be different.  Is there a better way to structure the code than with `#ifdef _WIN32`?
The current OS I am working on is Windows 10.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#endif

ArduinoDevice::ArduinoDevice(const char *dev)
{
    device = dev;
    fp = NULL;
    started = false;
    iostarted = false;
}

void ArduinoDevice::connect()
{
    #ifdef _WIN32
      //windows code
    #else 
      //mac code
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single neutral header file (e.g. ArduinoDevice.h) and more platform specific source files, one for each supported platform with extensions such as *.win32.cpp, *.posix.cpp (e.g. ArduinoDevice.win32.cpp, ArduinoDevice.posix.cpp, etc).

On each OS you will compile only the source files with the related extension, not requiring changes to the calling code. The conditional code (#ifdef #endif block) is not required, the use of a file or the other for compilation can be handled in the project build configuration.

Comment: but in the end, logically, you're going to have to have some sort of switch based on the OS.   The question is simply where.

Comment: Sure, a switch must be made somewhere. This approach improves code readability.

Comment: At the expense of having to delve into the build system to understand what code is being used in what situations.  I'd say there are pros and cons to each approach.

Answer (score 0):

Consider instead having your application logic call a library that abstracts the hardware knowledge.

Define

1. A header (bluetooth.h or similar) that provides the functions for the functionality you need (open, close, read, write, etc...), possibly bundled in a class
2. A different CPP file (winBluetooth.cpp, macBluetooth.cpp, etc...) for each platform
3. Possibly a CPP file full of common functionality to reduce code duplication.

Each platform-specific CPP file includes the correct headers and uses the platform-specific calls required to implement the functions in the header. This eliminates the need for conditional compilation and managing who needs what headers with more conditional compilation by pushing the problem from the code to the build system.

Building the program may get a bit trickier, but any development environment worth using will allow you to define different targets, the toolchain required to build the target, and which files are included in the build for the target. In the old days this would result in a few extra rules in a makefile. How it's done on your system varies from system to system.